# Access denied when trying to install Chocolatey from an elevated cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, chocolatey

I'm trying to install Chocolatey following the [instructions](https://chocolatey.org/install) on their website. So I run Command Prompt as an administrator but when trying to install Chocolatey I get a message in the cmd saying 'Access is denied'.

What could be the reason for this message ?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest run Process Monitor (Microsofft\Sysinternals), which running that command and see if you get an acess denied results.

Comment: Are you using an an [administrative shell](https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/)?